# how to Allow remote SQL connections from specific IP

Tags: sql-server, ssms

i use ms sql 2005 server . guide me: how to Allow remote SQL connections from specific IP.

Thank all

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections:

1. Click Start, point to Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Server 2005, point to Configuration Tools, and then click SQL Server Surface Area Configuration.
2. On the SQL Server 2005 Surface Area Configuration page, click Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections.
3. On the Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections page, expand Database Engine, click Remote Connections, click Local and remote connections, click the appropriate protocol to enable for your environment, and then click Apply. (Note : Click OK when you receive the following message:
   Changes to Connection Settings will not take effect until you restart the Database Engine service.)
4. On the Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections page, expand Database Engine, click Service, click Stop, wait until the MSSQLSERVER service stops, and then click Start to restart the MSSQLSERVER service.

Source: [Microsoft Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277)

Then to allow only specific IPs to access your MS SQL server, create a firewall rule that will allow this specific IP through TCP 1433 and TCP 1434, and block those ports from any other IPs.

Comment: Then to allow only specific IPs to access your MS SQL server, create a firewall rule that will allow this specific IP through TCP 1433 and TCP 1434, and block those ports from any other IPs.

Comment: i don't know  create a firewall rule that will alow this speccific ip through tcp 1433 anh 1434. Help me

Comment: What OS are you running?